# Type Korean on Ubuntu. Directions for 2023

Tags: input-language, korean

I can't seem to get Korean to work on my Ubuntu install despite trying everything.

Here's a video of my situation:

https://video.intcultcom.com/recordings/5EA5XQP3AeXm9AA4hkvC?uploadId=2Xahm1iXsySk6VqOhPXz

It's strange behavior, isn't it?

Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Comment: https://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2023/01/how-to-switch-ubuntu-desktop-language-to-korean.html is current

Comment: @Rinzwind: Maybe current in a sense, but it is about changing display language. This question is about typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the Korean XKB layout only, but you need a Korean input method.

- `sudo apt install ibus-hangul`
- Log out and log in again
- Go to Settings -> Keyboard and add Korean (Hangul) to your input sources.
- Switch to Korean (Hangul), enable Hangul mode, and have fun!

Comment: Thanks Gunnar! I was quite excited there for a minute. Sadly, however, that doesn't seem to have worked:

https://video.intcultcom.com/recordings/JP4n4E6fHZuBLLHgrpRl?uploadId=xY2V3XIlYhGWHS6jfYx1

As you can see in the video, I've done everything you told me to do, but I'm still typing in English. 

Any other ideas? Is there some setting portion I'm missing?

Comment: It appears as though I spoke too soon! I went into the language conversion section and clicked on "Setup" then changed it to "Start in Hangul mode" and then changed the Hangul toggle key. There was an error of some sort (didn't record it) but then after restarting the computer I was good to go.

I'm fine starting in Korean for now. Thanks for the help @Gunnar!!!

Comment: @intcultcom: N.p., great that you made it work at last.

Comment: Yup. Thanks to you.